# How validate param only if user is guest in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want validate name and email (do required) only if user is guest. How I can do it correctly?

I tried paste the `if` condition. But I don't think this is correct:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'body' => 'required|string',
        'type' => 'required|integer|in:1,2,3'
    ]);
} else {
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required|string',
        'type' => 'required|integer|in:1,2,3'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a validation rule that'll do this, but you can at least get the code a little cleaner by skipping the `else` condition, for instance like so:

```
$rules = [
    'body' => 'required|string',
    'type' => 'required|integer|in:1,2,3',
];

if (Auth::guest()) {
    $rules['name'] = 'required|string';
    $rules['email'] = 'required|string';
}

$request->validate($rules);
```

Another option would be to simply check the requirement within the array and just skip the field in the validation for authorised users. It's shorter, but not quite as clean:

```
$request->validate([
    'body' => 'required|string',
    'type' => 'required|integer|in:1,2,3',
    'name' => Auth::guest() ? 'required|string' : '',
    'email' => Auth::guest() ? 'required|string' : '',
]);
```

By the way, I would recommend validating the email address as an email address: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-email